# getting error Failed to execute 'getStats' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The callback-based getStats()

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVZMc.png)

hi guys i am using AgoraRTCSDK with version 3.6.11 and google chrome Version 118.0 and getting error which mention in above image. kindly help me to remove this.

i have read out this google developer blog which mention getStats is remove.

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/getstats-migration/

Answer (score 0):

As you describe in your post the function `getStats` used with a callback have been deprecated in favour of using Promises instead.

The [agora-rtc-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agora-rtc-sdk) have been deprecated so any updated on this package is not to be expected.

Unless you want to fix the deprecated package you might want to consider using the newer [agora-rtc-sdk-ng](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agora-rtc-sdk-ng) instead.